# Clear all files from file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a `<asp:FileUpload>` Control.

How can i clear Files from File upload Control with C# code without refresh page?

I tried:

```
fluFiles.ID = null;
```

fluFiles is my File Upload Control ID.please give suggestion if possible without JQuery.

Comment: Why do you need to 'clear' this control?

Comment: @ steve Because i have form in which i use popup Modal. i need to insert next data then previous image not remove that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 FileUpload.Attributes.Clear();
```

Or:

```
private void clearFileUpload()
{
    fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Dispose();
    // fileUpload.HasFile is now  false
}
```

Comment: What have the attributes to do with the file upload's selected files? Plus: your code looks like server-side code, the OP wants to have something _without_ refreshing the page; probably some client-side code.